# Sort the List by Date for Next 30 days and Display in List Box in C#

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on Facebook Birthdays List using Graph Api

By this Url Im Getting All My Friends Birthdays List

"https://graph.facebook.com/{0}?fields=friends.fields(birthday,id,name)&access_token={1}", fbid, acctocken"

After Getting Responce My Code is Like this

```
        var response = e.Result;
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
        jsonData.friends.data = jsonData.friends.data.OrderBy(BdayItems => BdayItems.birthday).ToList();
```

By Using the Above Linq Query I am sorting My Friends List By the Birthdays and I am display All My Friends Birthdays in my ListBox.

But I need More Like

I want to Display Only Next 30 days Birthdays from today

How can Make this in Easy way By using Linq Query or Any Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `BdayItems.birthday` is of type `string` you could do something like:

```
jsonData.friends.data = jsonData.friends.data.Where(BdayItems => BdayItems.birthday != null
                                                              && DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday) >= DateTime.Today
                                                              && DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday) <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(30))
                                             .OrderBy(BdayItems => DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday))
                                             .ToList();
```

**EDIT**: I was dumb and didn't account for before today. Also switched to assume `BdayItems.birthday` is of type `string` instead of `DateTime`. However, you still will have to catch errors in case `DateTime.Parse()` fails.

Comment: BdayItems.birthday is String type Hear, How can i do it Now @aladd04

Comment: I don't know the format that `BdayItems.birthday` is in, but I would suggest attempting to convert them to `DateTime` and then compare as done above. Check out the `DateTime.Parse()` and/or `DateTime.TryParse()` methods. Just be sure to catch errors.

Comment: Now My code is Like  this ===>    
 jsonData.friends.data = jsonData.friends.data.Where(BdayItems => (BdayItems.birthday != null && DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday) <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(30))).OrderBy(BdayItems => BdayItems.birthday).ToList();            But Im getting All Dates from Jan to Dec But I need Only Next 30 days From this Day ..

Comment: Some time if there is No Birthday in my list at that time im Not resiveing Birthday tag for that I am checking (BdayItems.birthday != null)...

Comment: I edited the response to better fit your exact needs. I was dumb and didn't account for before today (silly me). This worked for me in a test list I created. The only thing you'll still need to account for is incorrectly formatted `BdayItems.birthday` strings. `DateTime.Parse()` will throw an exception. So, if desired, you should look into a workaround for that. Though, hopefully the Facebok Graph API doesn't give bad strings :)

Answer (score 0):

Cover all cases to filter out birthdays including December case for January

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DateTime> birthdays = new List<DateTime>() {
            new DateTime(1977,1,29),
            new DateTime(1977,1,30),
            new DateTime(1977,1,31)
            };

            var daysFrom = 30;
            var start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day);
            start = new DateTime(2020, 12, 31); // border test case
            var last = start.AddDays(daysFrom);
            var yearSwitch = last.Year - start.Year;
            var res = birthdays.Where(bday =>
                {
                    var bn = new DateTime(start.Year, bday.Month, bday.Day);
                    if (bday.DayOfYear < daysFrom)
                    {
                        bn = bn.AddYears(yearSwitch);
                    }
                    return bn >= start && bn <= last;
                }
            ).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("List:{0}", string.Join(",", res));
        }
```